# Custom global planner

Tags: ros, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to create my own global planner.
So far I have created a simple path that should move robot for 0.5m to the left using "nav_msgs::Path mypath", and publish it to the "move_base/NavfnROS/plan" . The path is shown in the rviz, but robot doesn't start to move on it.

What am I missing? Or what would be the easiest way for me to "foward" my custom path to move_base (robot).

I only want to change global plan, I still want for local plan to work normally and avoid obstacles etc.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39119/custom-global-planner/) by [Darkmaster](https://answers.ros.org/users/2850/darkmaster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2012-07-18

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Darkmaster](https://answers.ros.org/users/2850/darkmaster/) on 2012-07-18**:
I think I need to implement BaseGlobalPlanner. Can you point me more on what to do? I'm still a beginner.

**Comment by [ngoldfarb](https://answers.ros.org/users/23280/ngoldfarb/) on 2016-01-12**:
How did you get the path to appear? I am publishing a nav_msgs Path mypath (in Python) but it will not appear in Rviz.

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-06-10**:
@Darkmaster please see [this](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're looking to integrate your new global planner with `move_base`, you should check out the code for [navfn](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navfn) and [carrot_planner](http://www.ros.org/wiki/carrot_planner). `carrot_planner` is much simpler for a global planner and it would be a really good place to start. There's only one source file and it's essentially a straight-line planner.

Essentially, your planner must implement two methods to fit the BaseGlobalPlanner interface:

```
void initialize(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros);
bool makePlan(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& start, const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& goal, std::vector<
  geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& plan);
```

The `initialize()` method acts as a replacement for the constructor. You should do all of your construction in this method instead of in the actual constructor.

The `makePlan()` method is the one that is called when `move_base` asks for a new plan.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you want some method to move the robot forward 0.5m or do you want to create a global planner (and this is just your test code)?

For the first, the easy way would be to construct a move base goal at 0.5m and specify it in the robot's frame.

For the second, did you implement the interface [BaseGlobalPlanner](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nav_core) and used that in move_base?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-07-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2